# Data from the email, the content is not showing in the solution, it's showing blank

Tags: web-part, email

I am developing a help desk software in SharePoint. I am using the out of box web parts as well as some customized one. Anyway, I have set up a flow that automatically creates a ticket for emails coming in at support. The flow is running OK and ticket is creating, but the problem is data from the email, the content is not showing in the solution, its showing blank. I don't understand why this is happening. Has anyone else faced this kind of issue? Please do share your thought on how I can fix this.